# Java Printwriter and css Issue

Tags: java, html, css, servlets, printwriter

I hava a java dynamic web project and I want to use PrintWriter with CSS. Text.ccs file location is in L/css. Please help me, thank you.

```
   String myCurrentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
        writer.println("<HTML>");       
        writer.println("<HEAD>");
        writer.println("<title>Report Foot</title>");
        writer.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\""+myCurrentDir+"/L/css/Test.css\">");
        writer.println("</HEAD>");
        writer.println("<body class = 'footer'>");
        writer.println("<B>");
        writer.println("myCurrentDir" +myCurrentDir);
        writer.println("<BR/>");
        writer.println("<BR/>");
        writer.close();
        writer.println("@ABC DEF XYZ");
        writer.println("</body>");
        writer.println("</HTML>");
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("Footer Written");
```

Comment: CSS file is not taken into account

Comment: Like 404 not found and it is not even loaded or there is something wrong with the CSS rules? You need to be as specific as possible.

Comment: there's no error, but the css is not applied.. as if it wouldn't exists.. I just tried to set background color to see that it works.

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? Try logging `myCurrentDir`.

Comment: yes, I tried...

Comment: any idea how other way could I do ?

Comment: @Cameron121341 What does it look like in Developer Tools?

Comment: html appears as it should, but there's nothing  related to the ccs file.